# Remove partially uninstalled C# application

Tags: c#, windows, installation, uninstallation

I have prepared windows application which contains windows form and windows services. While uninstalling the application some error occurred and application remains in partially uninstalled state.

Now when I am trying to install the application it is showing application is already installed. If I am trying to uninstall it is showing same error I got during uninstall.

Please tell me if anyone know how to overcome this problem.

I have already removed all the files and folders from program files for this application.

Answer (score 0):

The windows service may not be properly removed. Remove your windows service by using the below command line utility

```
installutil /u yourproject.exe
```

Comment: I was not able to remove the window service using this code... but your suggestion works... here is the code to remove the window service using cmd : "sc delete [service name]"